# Why should call lock_upgrade() of a boost::thread::shared_mutex block?

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I'm studying manual on **boost::thread** and they say that effect of calling **lock_upgrade()** of **shared_mutex** is 
*"The current thread blocks until upgrade ownership can be obtained for the current thread."*.

But why should it block, as upgrade ownership it's not yet an exclusive ownership?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> But why should it block, as upgrade ownership it's not yet an exclusive ownership?

If someone already has exclusive ownership, then no-one can obtain shared or upgradable ownership; so `lock_shared` and `lock_upgrade` will both block in that situation.

And, as noted in the comments, only one thread can have upgradable ownership; so `lock_upgrade` will also block if someone already has that.

Comment: You are correct, and as an additional note, only one thread is allowed to obtain upgradeable ownership at a time.  If another thread has obtained upgradeable ownership, the call to `lock_upgrade` will block.